# Footnote line on right side - Shorten the separator between the columns

Tags: footnotes, multicol

I have an Arabic text (RT language) in two columns shown in figure.
I use multicol package to make two columns.

please: 
(1) Is there any way to move the footnote line to right (to be above the the footnotes) ? 
(2) How to shorten the line which split these two columns?

[image]

here the code can produce the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.6]{Geeza Pro}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{ \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\RLmulticolcolumns

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \begin{Arabic}
         قرار أصدره مجلس الأمن يوم 14 أبريل/نيسان 2015 بموجب الفصل السابع من ميثاق الأمم المتحدة، يفرض حظرا للسلاح على الحوثيين وأنصار الرئيس اليمني المخلوع علي عبد الله صالح، ويدعو الحوثيين إلى الخروج من المدن والمناطق التي استولوا عليها بما فيها العاصمة صنعاء. صوتت 13 دولة لصالح القرار، ولم تعارض أي دولة، بينما امتنعت عن التصويت دولة واحده فقط هي روسيا.
         نص مشروع القرار
         إن مجلس الأمن إذ يشير إلى قراراته 2014 (2011) و2051 (2012) و2140 (2014) 
         و2201 (2015) و2204 (2015)، وإلى بيانات رئيسه المؤرخة 15 فبراير/شباط 2013 و29 أغسطس/آب 2014 و22 مارس/آذار 2015، وإذ يحيط علما بالرسالة المؤرخة 24 مارس/آذار 2015 الموجهة من الممثل الدائم لليمن لدى الأمم المتحدة، التي يحيل بها رسالة من رئيس اليمن يبلغ فيها رئيس مجلس الأمن أنه "قد طلب من مجلس التعاون لدول الخليج العربية وجامعة الدول العربية تقديم الدعم على الفور، بكل الوسائل والتدابير اللازمة، بما فيها التدخل العسكري، لحماية اليمن وشعبه من استمرار عدوان الحوثيين".
         وإذ يشير إلى الرسالة المؤرخة 26 مارس/آذار2015 الموجهة من الممثلة الدائمة لدولة قطر، التي تحيل بها رسالة من ممثلي الإمارات العربية المتحدة ومملكة البحرين ودولة قطر ودولة الكويت والمملكة العربية السعودية.
         وإذ يشير إلى قرار مؤتمر القمة السادس والعشرين لجامعة الدول العربية بشأن التطورات في اليمن.
         وإذ يؤكد في جملة أمور على ضرورة استئناف عملية الانتقال السياسي في اليمن بمشاركة جميع الأطراف اليمنية وفقا لمبادرة مجلس التعاون الخليجي، وآلية تنفيذها\footnote{نص للشرح هنا}، ونتائج مؤتمر الحوار الوطني الشامل.
         وإذ يؤكد من جديد التزامه القوي بوحدة اليمن وسيادته واستقلاله وسلامته الإقليمية، والتزامه بالوقوف إلى جانب شعب اليمن.
         وإذ يدين تزايد عدد ونطاق الهجمات التي يشنها تنظيم القاعدة في شبه الجزيرة العربية.
         وإذ يعرب عن القلق إزاء مقدرة تنظيم القاعدة في شبه الجزيرة العربية على الاستفادة من تدهور الأوضاع السياسية والأمنية في اليمن، آخذا في الاعتبار أن أي أعمال من أعمال الإرهاب هي أعمال إجرامية وغير مبررة بغض النظر عن الدوافع إليها، ووقت ارتكابها، ومكان ارتكابها، وأيا كان مرتكبها.
         وإذ يكرر تأكيد دعمه لما يبذله مجلس التعاون الخليجي من جهود لمؤازرة عملية الانتقال السياسي في اليمن، وإذ يثني على مشاركته في هذا الصدد.
         وإذ يعيد تأكيد تأييده لشرعية رئيس اليمن، عبدربه منصور هادي، وإذ يكرر دعوته كل الأطراف والدول الأعضاء أن تمتنع عن اتخاذ أي إجراءات من شأنها تقويض وحدة اليمن وسيادته واستقلاله وسلامته الإقليمية، والمسّ بشرعية رئيس اليمن.
         وإذ يعرب عن جزعه الشديد إزاء خطورة وسرعة تدهور الحالة الإنسانية في اليمن.
         وإذ يشدد على أن الحالة الإنسانية ستستمر في التدهور في ظل غياب الحل السياسي.
         وإذ يشير إلى أن حرمان المدنيين تعسفا من وصول المساعدات الإنسانية إليهم ومن المواد التي لا غنى عنها لبقائهم على قيد الحياة، بما في ذلك تعمّد عرقلة إمدادات الإغاثة ووصولها، يمكن أن يشكل انتهاكا للقانون الإنساني الدولي.
         وإذ يشدد على ضرورة العودة إلى تنفيذ مبادرة مجلس التعاون الخليجي وآلية تنفيذها ونتائج مؤتمر الحوار الوطني الشامل، بما يشمل صياغة دستور جديد، وإصلاح النظام الانتخابي، وإجراء استفتاء على مشروع الدستور، وتنظيم الانتخابات العامة في موعد قريب، لتفادي حدوث المزيد من التدهور في الحالة الإنسانية والأمنية في اليمن.

        \end{Arabic}
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe a way to raise the text (making a white space above the line) will work :)

Comment: Most users here (almost all) don't know arabic. A minimal test document showing the issue would be a good starting point for someone jumping in. Constructing an example from scratch. if you don't know the script is a bit much.

Comment: the rule separating the columns really doesn't extend lower than it needs to, to be even at the bottom with the marks below the letters on the last line in the right column.  perhaps a better approach would be to add a little more space above the footnote itself; you could use a `\vphantom` to do that.  (i'm not sufficiently familiar with the internals of the `multicol` package to try to shift the horizontal footnote separator to the right, but that would really be the best solution.)

Comment: @Johannes_B I've added a code example .

Comment: With `XeTeX`  don't load `inputenc` or `fontenc`, to right align the footnote rule you can just add this command `\rightfootnoterule` from `bidi` package.